# After upgrading to Wordpress 4.1 Blanc New Post Area, No Toolbar

Tags: wordpress, toolbar

Everything was working fine before upgrading to Wordpress 4.1

What Have I Done:

1. I disabled all the plugins, didn't work.
2. I changed the theme, didn't work.
3. Removed all the updated themes, and back to my default theme again, didn't work.
4. Added this code, define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M'); , to wp-config.php, did not work

PLEASE HELP

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it installed successfully? Why don't you try wp-reinstall button on the dashboard update page, or manual install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a "Permission" problem after I upgraded to 4.1 
The "tinymce" directory, sub-directories, and sub-files, was not have the permission 
So, I chmod the directory by chmod -R 755, and now It works just fine 
Problem solved after 3 days.